# Want to find matching strings within a column, by group, and condition

Tags: r

I have a list of a few companies with each line as a deal. My table indicates whether they had a Initial Public Offering (IPO) or not, and what bank lead the deal:

```
df <- data.frame(Issuer=c("ABC Inc.", "ABC Inc.","ABC Inc.", "XYZ Co.","XYZ Co","123 Inc.","123 Inc."),
             IPO=c("Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No"),
             Bank =c("RBC","RBC","CIBC","RBC","Goldman","Citi","Citi"))
```

I want to create a list of all **Issuers** where they have the same **Bank** when IPO=="Yes" AND IPO=="No" like so:

| Issuer | Bank |
| --- | --- |
| ABC Inc. | RBC |
| 123 Inc. | Citi |

I've been circling the problem like this:

```
temp = df %>% group_by(Issuer) %>% filter(Bank[IPO=="Yes"] == Bank[IPO=="No"])
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following groups the data by "Bank" and "Issuer", and checks to see if that combination has exactly two unique values for "IPO" (i.e., Yes and No). In that case, the Issuer/Bank combination meets your criteria. The rest of the dplyr chain filters down to the requested output information.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Issuer=c("ABC Inc.", "ABC Inc.","ABC Inc.", "XYZ Co.","XYZ Co","123 Inc.","123 Inc."),
                 IPO=c("Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No"),
                 Bank =c("RBC","RBC","CIBC","RBC","Goldman","Citi","Citi"))

df.new <- df %>% 
  group_by(Issuer, Bank) %>% 
  mutate(
    both_ipo = length(unique(IPO)) == 2
  ) %>% 
  filter(both_ipo) %>% 
  select(Issuer, Bank) %>% 
  distinct

  Issuer   Bank 
  <chr>    <chr>
1 ABC Inc. RBC  
2 123 Inc. Citi
```

You don't necessarily need to create the `both_ipo` flag, and could use it directly in `filter` like below, but I usually prefer to create any new attributes in a separate step so that I can check them.

```
df.new <- df %>% 
  group_by(Issuer, Bank) %>% 
  filter(length(unique(IPO)) == 2) %>% 
  select(Issuer, Bank) %>% 
  distinct
```

Comment: Unbelievable.....solved in the time it took me to go to the bathroom. Thank you very much. I spent too much time on this and just couldn't guess the vernacular. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Issuer, Bank) %>%
  filter(all(c('Yes', 'No') %in% IPO)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  distinct(Issuer, Bank)

#  Issuer   Bank 
#  <chr>    <chr>
#1 ABC Inc. RBC  
#2 123 Inc. Citi
```